# Minhas variáveis não estão sendo contadas no código

Tags: javascript, html, contador

Estou criando uma página para que o usuário digite uma quantidade de números e parar apenas quando ele digitar o número 0, logo após isso, iria abrir um alerta dizendo a quantidade de números que o usuário digitou, quantos são negativos, pares e ímpares, porém apenas a parte da quantidade está funcionando, alguem poderia me explicar o que eu poderia fazer para solucionar o código?

```
<script>

    var quantidade = 0
    var negativos = 0
    var pares = 0
    var impares = 0

    while (numeros != 0) {
        var numeros = window.prompt("Digite os números para serem lidos")
        if (numeros != 0) {
            quantidade++;
        } else if (numeros < 0) {
            negativos++;
        } else if (numeros % 2 === 0) {
            pares++;
        } else if (numeros / 2 == 1) {
            impares++;
        }
    }

    alert(`Foram inseridos ${quantidade} números\n${negativos} são negativos\n${pares} são pares\n${impares} são ímpares.`)

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso é por causa do `else if`. O `else` só é avaliado quando ocorre uma condição "contrária" ao `if`.

Imagina que digitou 1, o primeiro `if` é:

`if (numeros != 0) {` - essa condição é verdadeira, logo vai entrar aqui **e não vai entrar** em nenhum outro `else if`.

Você pode resolver isso simplesmente removendo o `else` das condições:

```
while (numeros != 0) {
    var numeros = window.prompt("Digite os números para serem lidos")
    if (numeros != 0) {
        quantidade++;
    } 
    if (numeros < 0) {
        negativos++;
    } 
    if (numeros % 2 === 0) {
        pares++;
    } 
    if (numeros / 2 == 1) {
        impares++;
    }
}
```

Mas isso vai fazer com que, ao digitar zero, ele passe descessariamente pelos `if`, e ainda vai somar 1 aos pares, precisa isolar isso.
Pode por exemplo por todas as condições somente se o valor for difernte de zero:

```
while (numeros != 0) {
    var numeros = window.prompt("Digite os números para serem lidos")
    if (!isNaN(numeros) && numeros != 0) {  // tudo é feito somente se "numeros" for diferente de zero
        quantidade++;
      
      if (numeros < 0) {
         negativos++;
      } 
      if (numeros % 2 === 0) {
          pares++;
      } else {  // senão for par, vai ser impar, não precisa avalisar o resto novamente
          impares++;
      }
    } 
}
```

Note que, no `if` foi adicionado `!isNaN(numeros)` ou seja "se numeoros não for NaN".  Nan significa que não um número, isso para evitar tentar fazer cálculos quem valores que não sejam números, por exemplo se digitar uma letra. Poderia até por um `if` isolado validando isso:

```
if (isNaN(numeros)) {
    alert("Digite apenas números");
    continue;
}
```

Aqui foi usado `continue` para voltar o `while`, sem continuar todo o código abaixo, já que não é um número válido :)

```js
var quantidade = 0
var negativos = 0
var pares = 0
var impares = 0

while (numeros != 0) {
  var numeros = window.prompt("Digite os números para serem lidos")
  if (isNaN(numeros)) {
    alert("Digite apenas números");
    continue;
  }

  if (numeros != 0 ) {
    quantidade++;

    if (numeros < 0) {
      negativos++;
    } 
    if (numeros % 2 === 0) {
      pares++;
    } else {
      impares++;
    }
  } 
}


alert(`Foram inseridos ${quantidade} números\n${negativos} são negativos\n${pares} são pares\n${impares} são ímpares.`)
```

Answer (score 4):

> alguém poderia me explicar o que eu poderia fazer para solucionar o código?

Reescrever o algoritmo.

- Dentro de laço infinito...
- Converta a entrada `numeros`, que é retornada por [`window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/window/prompt) como [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), em um objeto [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).
- Teste o resultado da conversão para saber se é um número, use [`NumberisNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN). Se o resultado da conversão não for um número termine a iteração do [`loop while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) e passe a próxima iteração com o comando [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue).
- Teste o resultado da conversão para saber se é zero. Se o resultado da conversão for zero encerra e abandona o `loop while` com o comando [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break).
- Incrementa a quantidade de números computados.
- Teste o número para saber se é negativo. Se for negativo incremente a variável `negativos`.
- Teste a paridade do número. Se o número for par incremente `pares`, caso contrário incremente `impares`;

```js
var quantidade = 0
var negativos = 0
var pares = 0
var impares = 0

while (true) {
  var numeros = window.prompt("Digite os números para serem lidos");
  numeros = parseInt(numeros);
  if (Number.isNaN(numeros)) continue;
  if (numeros == 0) break;
  quantidade++;
  if (numeros < 0) negativos++;
  if (numeros % 2 == 0) pares++;
  else impares++;
}

alert(`Foram inseridos ${quantidade} números\n${negativos} são negativos\n${pares} são pares\n${impares} são ímpares.`)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (numeros != 0) {
            quantidade++;
        } else if (numeros < 0) {
            negativos++;
        } else if (numeros % 2 === 0) {
            pares++;
        } else if (numeros / 2 == 1) {
            impares++;
        }
```

como a primeira condição `if` foi atendida, o código nem mesmo foi lido após os `else`.
O que está no laço do `else` só é lido se a condição para o `if` anterior não for satisfeita.